# Milvus, similarity search by vector id

Tags: vector, similarity, cosine-similarity, milvus, vector-database

I am trying to conduct a vector similarity search via vector's raw id (VarChar type).

For example, a vector consists of three fields :
*auto_id (int64), userId (VarChar), vectorField (FloatVector).*

One possible solution in my mind is like:

1. Retrieve the vector field vector1 of user1 by a query;
2. Conduct another search operation over vector to retrieve the topK
   vectors in milvus.

Is is possible that, **given userId = "uid1"**, retrieve the topK vectors by **a single query/search**

Comment: Milvus supports hybrid queries now: https://milvus.io/docs/v2.1.x/hybridsearch.md

Answer (score 1):

milvus does not currently support search by id.

Mainly milvus is used to do ann calculation, search by id function is more suitable for key-value database

Comment: Thank you for this answer. However, Milvus supports query with logical expression. I just feel like, why not merge this with ANN search, i.e., performs a query by id to get the vector field first. After that, a local/internal search via ANN can happen directly there without an extra search request. Thank you again for this answer.

Comment: The advantage of milvus is the computation between vectors, there is no performance optimization in id filtering, which will affect the performance when the vectors volume is large